# Python: passing coordinates from list to function

Tags: python, list, csv, coordinates, netcdf

I am using some code from a [workshop](https://github.com/Unidata/unidata-python-workshop/blob/a56daa50d7b343c7debe93968683613642d6b9f7/notebooks/netcdf-by-coordinates.ipynb) to extract data from netCDF files by the coordinates closest to my specified coordinates. When using just one set of coordinates I am able to extract the values I need without trouble as below:

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from math import pi
from numpy import cos, sin

def tunnel_fast(latvar,lonvar,lat0,lon0):
    '''
    Find closest point in a set of (lat,lon) points to specified point
    latvar - 2D latitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lonvar - 2D longitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lat0,lon0 - query point
    Returns iy,ix such that the square of the tunnel distance
    between (latval[it,ix],lonval[iy,ix]) and (lat0,lon0)
    is minimum.
    '''

    rad_factor = pi/180.0 # for trignometry, need angles in radians
    # Read latitude and longitude from file into numpy arrays
    latvals = latvar[:] * rad_factor
    lonvals = lonvar[:] * rad_factor
    ny,nx = latvals.shape
    lat0_rad = lat0 * rad_factor
    lon0_rad = lon0 * rad_factor
    # Compute numpy arrays for all values, no loops
    clat,clon = cos(latvals),cos(lonvals)
    slat,slon = sin(latvals),sin(lonvals)
    delX = cos(lat0_rad)*cos(lon0_rad) - clat*clon
    delY = cos(lat0_rad)*sin(lon0_rad) - clat*slon
    delZ = sin(lat0_rad) - slat;
    dist_sq = delX**2 + delY**2 + delZ**2
    minindex_1d = dist_sq.argmin()  # 1D index of minimum element
    iy_min,ix_min = np.unravel_index(minindex_1d, latvals.shape)
    return iy_min,ix_min

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('E:\wind_level2_1.nc', 'r')
latvar = ncfile.variables['latitude']
lonvar = ncfile.variables['longitude']

#_________GG turbine_________GAD10  Latitude    51.735516, GAD10    Longitude   1.942656

iy,ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, 51.735516, 1.942656)
print('Closest lat lon:', latvar[iy,ix], lonvar[iy,ix])

refLAT=latvar[iy,ix]
refLON = lonvar[iy,ix]
#try to find the data for this location

SARwind = ncfile.variables['sar_wind'][:,:]
ModelWind = ncfile.variables['model_speed'][:,:]

print 'iy,ix' #appears to be the index of the value of Lat,lon
print SARwind[iy,ix]


ncfile.close()
```

Now I am trying to loop through a text file containing coordinates `coord_list` to extract sets of coordinates, find the data then move to the next set of coordinates in the list. This code works on it's own as below:

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal
with open('Turbine_locs_no_header.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #coord_list = list(reader)
    coord_list = [reader]
    end_row = len(coord_list)

    lon_ind=1
    lat_ind=2

for row in range(0, end_row-1):#end_row - 1 due to the 0 index
    turbine_lat = coord_list[row][lat_ind]
    turbine_lon = coord_list[row][lon_ind]
    turbine_lat = [Decimal(turbine_lat)]
    print 'lat',turbine_lat, 'lon',turbine_lon, row
```

However, I want to pass coordinates from the text file to this part of the original code `iy,ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, 51.94341, 1.922094888)`, replacing the numbers with variables `iy, ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, turbine_lat, turbine_lon)`. I try to combine the two codes by creating a function `get_coordinates`, I get the following errors

```
  File "C:/Users/mm/test_nc_bycoords_GG_turbines_AGW.py", line 65, in <module>
    get_coordinates(coord_list, latvar, lonvar)
  File "C:/Users/mm/test_nc_bycoords_GG_turbines_AGW.py", line 51, in get_coordinates
    iy, ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, turbine_lat, turbine_lon)
  File "C:/Users/mm/test_nc_bycoords_GG_turbines_AGW.py", line 27, in tunnel_fast
    lat0_rad = lat0 * rad_factor
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I thought this is because the `turbine_lat` and `turbine_lon` are list items so cannot be used, but this doesn't seem to be connected to the errors. I know this code needs more work anyway, but if anyone could help me spot where I am going wrong that would be very helpful. My attempt to combine the two codes is below.

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from math import pi
from numpy import cos, sin
import csv

# edited from https://github.com/Unidata/unidata-python-workshop/blob/a56daa50d7b343c7debe93968683613642d6b9f7/notebooks/netcdf-by-coordinates.ipynb

def tunnel_fast(latvar,lonvar,lat0,lon0):
    '''
    Find closest point in a set of (lat,lon) points to specified point
    latvar - 2D latitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lonvar - 2D longitude variable from an open netCDF dataset
    lat0,lon0 - query point
    Returns iy,ix such that the square of the tunnel distance
    between (latval[it,ix],lonval[iy,ix]) and (lat0,lon0)
    is minimum.
    '''

    rad_factor = pi/180.0 # for trignometry, need angles in radians
    # Read latitude and longitude from file into numpy arrays
    latvals = latvar[:] * rad_factor
    lonvals = lonvar[:] * rad_factor
    ny,nx = latvals.shape
    lat0_rad = lat0 * rad_factor
    lon0_rad = lon0 * rad_factor
    # Compute numpy arrays for all values, no loops
    clat,clon = cos(latvals),cos(lonvals)
    slat,slon = sin(latvals),sin(lonvals)
    delX = cos(lat0_rad)*cos(lon0_rad) - clat*clon
    delY = cos(lat0_rad)*sin(lon0_rad) - clat*slon
    delZ = sin(lat0_rad) - slat;
    dist_sq = delX**2 + delY**2 + delZ**2
    minindex_1d = dist_sq.argmin()  # 1D index of minimum element
    iy_min,ix_min = np.unravel_index(minindex_1d, latvals.shape)
    return iy_min,ix_min
#________________my edits___________________________________________________
def get_coordinates(coord_list, latvar, lonvar):
    "this takes coordinates from a .csv and assigns them to variables"

    end_row = len(coord_list)

    lon_ind=1
    lat_ind=2

    for row in range(0, end_row-1):#end_row - 1 due to the 0 index
        turbine_lat = coord_list[row][lat_ind]
        turbine_lon = coord_list[row][lon_ind]
        iy, ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, turbine_lat, turbine_lon)
        print('Closest lat lon:', latvar[iy, ix], lonvar[iy, ix])

#________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('NOGAPS_wind_level2_1.nc', 'r')
latvar = ncfile.variables['latitude']
lonvar = ncfile.variables['longitude']

#____added in to pass to get coordinates function
with open('Turbine_locs_no_header.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    coord_list = list(reader)
#_________take latitude from coordinateas function

get_coordinates(coord_list, latvar, lonvar)

#iy,ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, turbine_lat, turbine_lon)#get these from the 'assign_coordinates_fromlist.py
#print('Closest lat lon:', latvar[iy,ix], lonvar[iy,ix])

SARwind = ncfile.variables['sar_wind'][:,:]
ModelWind = ncfile.variables['model_speed'][:,:]

print 'iy,ix' #appears to be the index of the value of Lat,lon
print SARwind[iy,ix]


ncfile.close()
```

When I try to convert

Comment: Can you update the code formatting in your first code example please. I would but its not 6 characters worth of updates.

Comment: @EmettSpeer. I've fixed the indentation in the first section, what else needs sorting?

Comment: I only spotted the one formatting issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from a_guest

It was a simple problem of `lat0` and `lon0` being passed as 
`<type 'str'>` to `tunnel_fast` when it requires `<type 'float'>`. This appears to come from loading the `coord_list` as a list.

```
with open('Turbine_locs_no_header.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    coord_list = list(reader)
```

The workaround I used was to convert `lat0` and `lon0` to floats at the beginning of `tunnel_fast`

```
lat0 = float(lat0) 
lon0 = float(lon0)
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack an argument list using `*args` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)). In your case you could do `tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, *coord_list[row])`. You need to make sure that the order of arguments in `coord_list[row]` is correct and if `coord_list[row]` contains more than the two values then you need to slice it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, the traceback error is the same as the one above with `iy, ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, *coord_list[row])` instead of `iy, ix = tunnel_fast(latvar, lonvar, turbine_lat, turbine_lon)`

Comment: The problem is that `lat0` (for example) is of type `list` and thus doesn't support multiplication by `float` (though multiplication by `int` is probably not what you want either!). Check `print type(lat0)` and `print lat0` at the beginning of `tunnel_fast` and you'll see. You're somehow passing the wrong arguments.

Comment: Yes you're right. in the working version of the code it is `<type 'float'>` and `<type 'str'>` in the non working version.